# Why systemd dont restart service?

Tags: systemd

Pls help.
I have such Unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kafka_obed_exporter
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
After=kafka.service
Requires=kafka.service

[Service]
User=kafka_exporter
Group=kafka_exporter
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kafka_exporter --kafka.server=1.1.29.3:9092 --web.listen-address=1.1.29.2:9500
restart=always
RestartSec=10s
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

when i`m reboot server this unit try start only once and after this - fail with error:

```
kafka_exporter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
kafka_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

i know reason why its fail - other kafka node didnt start yet, when i manually restart unit - it started fine.
My question is why systemd doesn`t restart this unit ? as you can see im use options Restart=always, i think systemd will try restart this unit if it not started yet.
In systemd log i`m:

```
Dec 28 09:05:29 audmain systemd[1]: Started Apache Zookeeper.
Dec 28 09:05:29 audmain systemd[1]: Started Apache Kafka.
Dec 28 09:05:29 audmain systemd[1]: Started Kafka_obed_exporter.
Dec 28 09:05:29 audmain systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Service...
.......
.......
Dec 28 09:05:36 audmain systemd[1]: kafka_exporter.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Dec 28 09:05:36 audmain systemd[1]: kafka_exporter.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not restart because you wrote `restart=always` instead of `Restart=always`. Things on unix/linux are cases-sensitive.

Also, managing unit dependencies is the main business of systemd. You can tell it to start an unit after another unit. See the [digitalocean.com tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files) or `man systemd.unit`.

Comment: So if i change restart to Restart it`s help ? Thx

Comment: simple mistake broken my head :( sorry for that questions.